# What is causing the segmentation fault error in in this tiny c program?

Tags: c

I am writing a small c program to practicing `malloc` and `sscanf` library functions. But unfortunately I get a segmentation fault error. I have googled and struggled for hours but with no result. Anybody could lead me out of this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(int a[], int num_elements);

int main(void) {
    int m;    
    printf("How many numbers do you count: \n");  
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int *a = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));
    char buf[100];
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
        char *p = buf;
        int n, index;
        while (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n) == 1 && index < m) {
            // do something with array[i]
            index++;  // Increment after success @BLUEPIXY
            p += n;
        }
        if (*p != '\0')
            printf("you are giving non-numbers, will be ignored");
    }

    print_array(a, m);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}

void print_array(int a[], int num_elements) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int* a = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));` You are allocating an array for the size of `m` pointers, not `m` `int`s.

Comment: `int n, index;` --> `int n, index = 0;`

Comment: `sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n) == 1 && index < m` --> `index < m && sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n) == 1`

Comment: start using gdb. end of your horros

Comment: `int n, index;
 while (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n) == 1 && index < m)`
You store something in &a[index] whereas index is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has multiple errors:

- you do not check the return value of `scanf()`. Invalid input will cause `m` to remain uninitialized, allocating `m * sizeof(int)` may fail.
- The size computed for `malloc` is incorrect. Casting the return value of `malloc()` is not necessary in C and considered bad style. Furthermore, you should check for allocation failure. Use this instead:

  ```
  int *a = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
  ```
- `index` is uninitialized in `sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n)` definitely causing undefined behavior as you are telling `sscanf()` to store the `int` value into some random address in memory.
- you test `index < m` **after** storing to `&a[index]`, causing a potential buffer overflow.  Swap the test in front of the `sscanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(const int a[], int num_elements);

int main(void) {
    int m;    
    printf("How many numbers do you count:\n");  
    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1 || m <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int *a = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[100];
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);  // why do you want stdin to be unbuffered?
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
        char *p = buf;
        int n, index = 0;
        while (index < m && sscanf(p, "%d %n", &a[index], &n) == 1) {
            // do something with array[i]
            index++;  // Increment after success @BLUEPIXY
            p += n;
        }
        if (*p != '\0') {
            printf("you are giving non-numbers or extra input, will be ignored\n");
        }
    }

    print_array(a, m);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}

void print_array(const int a[], int num_elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `malloc` is faulty. Replace `int* a = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));` with `int* a = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));`.
You got lucky here, that `sizeof` `int` is smaller than `int*`, otherwise you can get in whole bunch of problems.

I couldn't reproduce the error, better give input text next time, but to debug segfault i depend on gdb.

$ gcc **-g** prog.c -o prog

$ gdb prog

gdb> run [args]

This will break the program at line which is causing segfault. Use this tutorial for more knowledge. [gdb tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Most [potential] causes of errors seem to come from not initializing your automatic variables:

```
scanf("%d",&m);
```

If this fails, then `m` has an undefined value as you didn't initialize it.

in `sscanf` you use `&a[index]` but `index` has not been initialized so it can be written anywhere.

See also the comments, that identify more erors (e.g. checking the return value of `sscanf`).